# How can I get all the Attribute and Values from SAML response?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, saml, saml-2.0

I have implemented SSO using Azure ADFS and used SAML, and below is my SAML Response from Azure.

```
<saml2:AttributeStatement xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<saml2:Attribute Name="User.email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <saml2:AttributeValue 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Rudresh@gmail.com
    </saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute>
    
<saml2:Attribute Name="emailaddress" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <saml2:AttributeValue 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">rudresh@google.com
    </saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute>
</saml2:AttributeStatement>
```

I want to extract all the attributes and Values from the above SAML response like below.

```
User.Email = 'Rudresh@gmail'
emailAddress = 'rudresh@google.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the response to an xml object and then map the values to the desired properties.
To sum it up, once the [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netcore-3.1) has completed and converted the response to an object,
 Using [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) we are able to go in and find the [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1) `emailaddress` and `User.email` Attribute and assign them to both `EmailAddress` and `Email` properties all within the object constructor.
Here is an example how to use it within a console application.

```
// Your above payload.
string examplePayload = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("TextFile1.txt");

// Creating the saml response.
SamlResponse samlResponse = new SamlResponse(examplePayload);

// writing the output, rudresh@google.com
Console.WriteLine(samlResponse.EmailAddress);
```

And here is the response class.

```
public class SamlResponse
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; }
    public string Email { get; }

    public SamlResponse(string saml2)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(saml2)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(saml2));

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saml2)))
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AttributeStatement));
            AttributeStatement response = (AttributeStatement)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(ms);
            EmailAddress = response.Attribute.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "emailaddress").AttributeValue?.TrimEnd();
            Email = response.Attribute.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "User.email").AttributeValue?.TrimEnd();
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [Serializable()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion")]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class AttributeStatement
    {

        private AttributeStatementAttribute[] attributeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement("Attribute")]
        public AttributeStatementAttribute[] Attribute
        {
            get
            {
                return this.attributeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.attributeField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [Serializable()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion")]
    public partial class AttributeStatementAttribute
    {
        private string attributeValueField;

        private string nameField;

        private string nameFormatField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string AttributeValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.attributeValueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.attributeValueField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string NameFormat
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameFormatField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameFormatField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you implement the SAML? Did you use a stack?

The easiest way to do this is to use a [SAML library](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) and it will do all the work for you - as well as checking signature etc.